# Promote a post on Social Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, facebook, social

I need an information, I'm starting to use Social Studio for a client of mine.
He would, after a post is published, promote his post to a certain target.
By official documentation it seems possible, but when I try to access to this feature the icon is greyed out and a popup says to log in Social.com.
Maybe it's because is it necessary to have MC Adveritising studio too?
What is Social.com?
Anyone could help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to boost your posts to specific audiences directly from within Social studio but you need to have this functionality enabled first as it is an integration with Advertising Studio. Depending on the version license of Social Studio your client has, it might be included or come at an additional cost. Best to have them reach out to their Salesforce account executive, to check what is required to enable this feature.

Only Social Studio licenses enabled for Advertising Studio will see the Ad campaigns powered by Ad Studio checkbox and the Register User for Ad Studio checkbox. Licenses without Social.com provisioned will not see these checkboxes.

More info here:
[http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/social_studio/publish/create_posts/postpromoting/][1]

Hope this helps!

Filip